# Merge duplicate json elements using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, merge

I want to perform a de-duplication of image files I have on disc. I have a json file that describes pairs of duplicates (output from duplicate-image-finder). If i were to configure auto-delete rules, because there are often more than two duplicate images, there's a risk I could unlink all image instances. Sample json file looks like this:

```
{"images" : [
    {"image1": "./folder1/IMG_013251.jpg", "image2": "./folder3/IMG_013251.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder1/IMG_013251.jpg", "image2": "./folder5/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder1/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "image2": "./folder4/IMG-WA0125.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder5/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "image2": "./folder4/IMG-WA0125.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder2/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "image2": "./folder3/IMG-WA0125.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder3/IMG_045262.jpg", "image2": "./folder8/IMG_013251.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder4/IMG-WA0024.jpg", "image2": "./folder1/IMG-WA0079.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder5/IMG-WA0130.jpg", "image2": "./folder4/IMG-WA0024.jpg", "similarity": 100}]}
```

My first thought was to modify the json to look like this but can't work out the logic:

```
{"images" : [
    {"image1": "./folder1/IMG_013251.jpg", "image2": "./folder3/IMG_013251.jpg", "image3": "./folder5/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "similarity": 100},    
    {"image1": "./folder1/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "image2": "./folder4/IMG-WA0125.jpg", "image3": "./folder5/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "similarity": 100},  
    {"image1": "./folder2/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "image2": "./folder3/IMG-WA0125.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder3/IMG_045262.jpg", "image2": "./folder8/IMG_013251.jpg", "similarity": 100},
    {"image1": "./folder4/IMG-WA0024.jpg", "image2": "./folder1/IMG-WA0079.jpg", "image3": "./folder5/IMG-WA0130.jpg", "similarity": 100}]}
```

My initial approach was to create two lists, then compare every element with every other element, dropping duplicates into a dictionary. I tried this and it didn't give me useful output. I have also looked at the dict.update() method but I'm not sure how to first identify the duplicate dicts. How else could I approach this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to calculate the equivalence sets.

Basically, assuming the similarity relation is transitive, you would iterate over the list of couples and generates the set of all equivalent pictures. Then take out one instance from the set and unlink the others.

For example, the sets based on your data would be:

```
set1 = {"./folder1/IMG_013251.jpg", "./folder5/IMG-WA0149.jpg", "./folder4/IMG-WA0125.jpg", "./folder3/IMG_045262.jpg", }
set2 = {"./folder4/IMG-WA0024.jpg", "./folder1/IMG-WA0079.jpg", "./folder5/IMG-WA0130.jpg"}
```

From this, you can choose an instance to save and unlink the others.

A way to calculate the equivalence set with your data layout is:

```
set_lists = []
for couple in dict["images"]:
    if couple["similarity"] > thresh:
        img1 = couple["image1"]
        img2 = couple["image2"]
        for eq_set in set_lists:
            if img1 in eq_set:
                eq_set.add(img2)
                break
            elif img2 in eq_set:
                eq_set.add(img1)
                break
         else:
             new_set = set([img1, img2])
             set_lists.append(new_set)
```